# Как в юнит-тестах сделать mock для файловой системы?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, mock

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека или метод создания в юнит-тестах моков для работы с файловой системой? В моём конкретном случае у меня есть методы которые тестируют наличие файла на диске и читают дату создания, возможно в будущем мне понадобятся и другие возможности.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How do you mock out the file system in C# for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087351/5752652) от участника  [@pupeno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6068/pupeno).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1087351/

Answer (score 1):

Установите NuGet пакет [`System.IO.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Abstractions). [Не от вендора](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions), но всё-таки готовый и [с поддержкой анализаторов roslyn](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions.Analyzers).

Более ранняя версия ответа на en so содержала классическую рекомендацию выделить интерфейс и дальше уже мокать его своей библиотекой тестирования.

> ```
> interface IFileSystem {
>     bool FileExists(string fileName);
>     DateTime GetCreationDate(string fileName);
> }
> ```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа  [How do you mock out the file system in C# for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087431/5752652) от участника  [@Matt Howells](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16881/matt-howells).</sub>